# Drawing cards problem

Tags: probability

We draw $13$ cards from a deck of $52$ cards, without replacement. Calculate the probability
that exactly $4$ face cards were drawn and there are at most $3$ spades among these figures. (An ace is a figure).

I know the $ \Omega$ is $\binom{52}{ 13}$, the |A1|chance of drawing four face cards $\binom{16} 4$ and ,at most" 3 spades might be $$\binom{39} 4 + \binom{13}{ 1}*\binom{39}{3} +\binom{13}{ 2}*\binom{39}{ 2} + \binom{13}{ 3} \binom{39} {1}$$. My question is whether it is a correct way of thinking and if so, how should I connect ,four face cards'' and at most 3 spades" in terms of calculus notation.

Thanks a bunch for help, just beginning my probability experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ denote the number of face cards that are drawn and let $S$
denote the number of spades among these face cards.

Then: $$P\left(F=4,S\leq3\right)=P\left(F=4\right)-P\left(F=4,S=4\right)=\frac{\binom{16}{4}\binom{36}{9}}{\binom{52}{13}}-\frac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{9}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

Be aware that $\{F=4,S=4\}$ is the event that $4$ face cards are drawn that are moreover spades.